# Equations of the sides an equilateral triangle with centroid at the origin and one side is $x+y=1$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> An equilateral triangle has its centroid at the origin and one side is $x+y=1$. Find the equations of the other sides.

**My Attempt**

[image]

$$
OD=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\implies OC=\sqrt{2}\implies C=(-1,-1)\\
m_{AB}=m_1=-1\implies\tan60=\sqrt{3}=|\frac{m+1}{1-m}|\\
\sqrt{3}-m\sqrt{3}=m+1\quad\text{or}\quad m\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{3}=m+1\\
m(1+\sqrt{3})=\sqrt{3}-1\quad\text{or}\quad m(\sqrt{3}-1)=\sqrt{3}+1\\
m=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}\quad\text{or}\quad m=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1}\\
y+1=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}(x+1)\quad\text{or}\quad y+1=\frac{\sqrt{3}+1}{\sqrt{3}-1}(x+1)
$$
But, my reference gives the solutions

$$y+1=\frac{\sqrt{3}-1}{\sqrt{3}+1}(x+1)$$

and

$$y\pm1=3+\sqrt{3}(x-1)$$

So, what are the actual solution to the problem and the easiest way to solve it?

Comment: The reference solution must be wrong. The slope of $y\pm1=3+\sqrt{3}(x-1)$ is $\sqrt{3}$ and hence inclination with x-axis is $60^{\circ}$, but it can't have a $60^{\circ}$ angle with $AB$ in that case.

Comment: If that $\pm$ is really supposed to be there in the last equation, your reference solution gives _three_ lines, not two, so it’s definitely suspect. It’s certainly not the first time that an answer key was wrong, and it won’t be the last. Plot both yours and the reference answers to see which one is more likely to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

The coordinates of the vertices of the triangle are found  to be $$A=(\frac {1+\sqrt 3}{2}, \frac {1-\sqrt 3}{2})$$

$$B=(\frac {1-\sqrt 3}{2}, \frac {1+\sqrt 3}{2})$$

$$C= (-1,-1)$$

The equations of lines passing through these points are 
$$ CA: y+1=\frac {\sqrt 3 -1}{\sqrt 3+1}(x+1)$$

$$ CB:   y+1=\frac {\sqrt 3 +1}{\sqrt 3-1}(x+1)$$

$$ AB: x+y=1$$

Thus your calculations are correct.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve it is as follows:

Because the side $x+y=1$ makes the 135° angle with the x-axis and the triangle is equilateral, the other two sides make the 135° - 60° = 75° and 135° - 120° = 15° angles with the x-axis, respectively.

Therefore, their slopes are

$$ \tan(75^\circ) = 2+\sqrt{3}$$

$$ \tan(15^\circ) = 2-\sqrt{3}$$

and their equations passing the vertex C = (-1,-1) are

$$y+1=(2\pm \sqrt{3})(x+1)$$

Yours are the same after rationalizing the denominators.

Comment: So the solution in my attempt is right ?.

Comment: I believe so, after simplification.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating the coordinate system by $\pm \frac{2 \pi}{3}$ gives the new coordinates $(x', y')$ defined by
$$(x', y') = \left(\frac{-x \mp \sqrt{3} y}{2} , \frac{\pm \sqrt{3} x - y}{2}\right) .$$
So, rotating the line $x + y = 1$ gives the equation $x' + y' = 1$, and substituting the above transformation equation to write this in terms of $x, y$ gives:
$$1 = \left(\frac{-x \mp \sqrt{3} y}{2}\right) + \left( \frac{\pm \sqrt{3} x - y}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\left(-1 \pm \sqrt 3\right) x + \left(-1 \mp \sqrt 3\right) y\right] .$$
But rearranging shows that this equation is equivalent to your solution.